# Retrieve V3 and V4 media sizes supported by a printer using UWP

Tags: c#, printing, uwp

I have a requirement to enumerate V3 and V4 media sizes supported by a printer using UWP.

Have gone through PrintHelper class which is able to show the media size options for a selected print queue in the print dialog launched through ShowPrintUIAsync() call.

But I want to enumerate the media sizes for a given print queue without launching print dialog.
Please let me know if there is any way to achieve.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you please detail  what  are "V3 and V4 media sizes" ?

Comment: I was talking of V3 and V4 printer drivers. In UWP presently all the capabilities (like media size, type, orientation etc) of an installed printer is shown in print dialog of UWP application while printing. I want to enumerate all the printer capabilities of installed print queues without user interaction from a Modern app/ UWP . Basically I am looking at UI less user interaction.